# ¿Cómo sumar horas, minutos y segundos, de manera incremental, cuando los datos vienen de la base de datos?

Tags: mysql, php7

[image: tabla donde se guardan loas datos]Explico un poco mejor mi pregunta:
Tengo una base de datos en la cual guardo una hora inicial y una hora final, y saco de estas dos la diferencia con la función diff() para poder conocer la duración de la actividad realizada entre esas dos horas.
El problema está en que quiero mostrar la suma de todas esas horas de actividad para poder mostrarla en una tabla que tengo montada en un PDF de FPDF.
Por ejemplo: una actividad comenzó a las 10:00:00 am y culminó a las 10:30:00 am; se supone que la duración fue de 30 minutos. Luego tengo otra actividad comprendida entre las 09:00:00 am y las 10:00:00 am, o sea que la duración es de 1 hora.
Todo eso se guarda en mi base de datos de manera normal y puedo mostrar tanto las dos horas como las direferencias entre las mismas a través de un foreach realizado a la variable que me trae las filas de la tabla, pero mi problema radica en poder sumar los valores guardados en el campo donde guardo la duración de las actividades, es decir, no consigo la manera de poder sumar dinámicamente todas las duraciones que vengan de la base de datos para poder mostrar esa 01:30:00 que según duraron los dos eventos descritos en mi ejemplo.

Comment: podrías mostrar tablas para comprender mejor que es lo que quieres que te devuelva la consulta.

Comment: Ahí está una captura de la tabla.

Comment: Sería que me ddevolviera la sumantoria de todo lo que está en el campo "tiempoTotal"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **TIME_TO_SEC**, para convertir a segundos los dos campos de horas, le restas una a otra, posterior a esto lo divides entre 60 (cantidad de minutos):

Te queda algo así(muestra los dos registros):

```
SELECT ((TIME_TO_SEC(a.horaFinal)-TIME_TO_SEC(a.horaPauta))/60) AS minutos FROM tempseguimientoproduccion AS a
```

Posterior a esto solo seria sumar los dos resultados:

```
SELECT SUM((TIME_TO_SEC(a.horaFinal)-TIME_TO_SEC(a.horaPauta))/60) AS minutos FROM tempseguimientoproduccion AS a
```

Comment: ¿Eso lo ejecuto en el archivo php donde quiero mostrar los datos? Disculpa la molestia.

Comment: Es una consulta SQL, esa la ejecutas y te regresa la sumatoria de los registros.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo guardo ese resultado en una variable para poder imprimirlo?

Comment: De la misma forma que imprimes un query de SQL, no se si usas algún framework, o es php puro.

Comment: Uso PHP puro. Pero gracias, ya logré imprimir el resultado el query.